# On Dual Pivot Quicksort

Tags: sorting, pivot, complexity-theory, big-o, quicksort

Quicksort is well known as one of the most powerful sorting algorithms. I was thinking how we can improve the algorithm by adding a second pivot. I did a bit of research and found out that it's already been implemented but not explained very well. Can anyone please elaborate on improvement that can be gained by having new pivots in quicksort.

Comment: Here are the best explanations I've found so far: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.core-libs.devel/2628 http://java.dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-quicksort-three

Comment: There are similar discussions you can find at math.stackexchange.com